# How can we improve Stack Overflow job matches?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I recently received an email from Stack Overflow saying:

> We found new job matches for you! We've cooked up these matches based on your location and interests.

I was surprised how far off the mark the matches were. Almost all of the matches were for positions I wouldn't want, am not fit for, or that require knowledge of languages I've never used.

The email also said:

> To improve your matches, you can update your preferences at any time.

My preferences were as I expected. I updated them to be more specific, but afterward - the matches seem to be about the same in quality.

I felt like writing a letter to SO, and the *Send us your feedback* link lead me to 'meta.'

I'm not sure how to say, "*Wow, I'm not looking for a new position - but these job matches are terrible.*" in a question that can be answered - but here is an account of that experience.

It seems like SO Jobs could connect its jobs with data found on the site. I, for example - have never even looked at an SO post about Java, so I shouldn't be getting job matches for "Senior Java engineer" - or should I?

Comment: Thanks for this. This Q may have been closed as dupe (and probably for good reason), but it's important that we hear this so the signal comes in loud and clear. I appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah. I looked it up the best I could, but it's clearly a duplicate - and the OP wrote about it in solid detail. More than anything, it just seems like a loss of revenue for SO, and I want them to make money. : )